# Create a certain matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

Does anyone know a fast way to create a matrix
like the following one in R.

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    1
[2,]    1    2    2    2
[3,]    1    2    3    3
[4,]    1    2    3    4
```

The matrix above is 4x4 and I want to create something like 10000x10000.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft. OP just wants a 4-by-4 matrix. `&` is just a field separator like some languages (e.g. LaTeX) use. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do:

```
N <- 4
m <- matrix(nrow = N, ncol = N)
m[] <- pmin.int(col(m), row(m))
```

or a shorter version as suggested by @dickoa:

```
m <- outer(1:N, 1:N, pmin.int)
```

These also work and are both faster:

```
m <- pmin.int(matrix(1:N, nrow = N, byrow = TRUE),
              matrix(1:N, nrow = N, byrow = FALSE))

m <- matrix(pmin.int(rep(1:N, each = N), 1:N), nrow = N)
```

Finally, here is a cute one using a matrix product but it is rather slow:

```
x <- matrix(1, N, N)
m <- lower.tri(x, diag = TRUE) %*% upper.tri(x, diag = TRUE)
```

---

Note that a 10k-by-10k matrix for R seems big, I hope you don't run out of memory.

Comment: this one liner should do this too `outer(1:4, 1:4, pmin)`

Comment: @dickoa: I was concerned that `pmin` would be called more than once, but no. So yes, that's another good suggestion.

Comment: also, `pmax.int()` may be faster still if you are working with just integers.

Comment: Here's another ugly, cryptic, slow one :) `chol2inv(chol(matrix(c(rep(c(2,-1,rep(0,N-2),-1),N-1),1),N,N)))`